# Using Switch with enum in C++

Tags: c++

For the following code I want to enter day and get cout value.
Currently it gives cout value correctly if i enter 0,1,2,3
Exp result:C++ program asks for a day and outputs the label of the day in a week.Please advise how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

enum days { Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu,Fri,Sat };
int day;
cout << " Enter a day ";
cin >> day;

switch (day)
{
case 0:
    cout << "Weekend" << endl;
    break;

case 1:
    cout << "Start of work week " << endl;
    break;

case 2:
    cout << "Midweek" << endl;
    break;

case 3:
    cout << "Midweek" << endl;
    break;

case 4:
    cout << "Midweek" << endl;
    break;

case 5:
    cout << "End of work  week" << endl;
    break;

case 6:
    cout << "Weekend" << endl;
    break;

default:
   cout << "Invalid day of the week" << endl;
    return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: You should be using `switch (day) case Sun:` `case Mon;`, `case Tue:`, shouldn't you?

Comment: i tried using  case Mon;, case Tue: but its throwing me error for case  Mon -Fri as weeknd ,Its good for sat and sun.I am not sure why its showing weeknd for mon -fri?Any help ?

Comment: Can't give you any help, because I can't see what you tried from where I'm sitting, and I can't see what *throwing me error* means.

Comment: I told you how to fix it in my first comment. I don't understand your difficulty. In your `switch`, replace `0` with `Sun`, `1` with `Mon`, `2` with `Tue`, and so forth. It doesn't *throw* anything, and it doesn't break anything.

Comment: Ok lets keep it simple .For Mon-Fri also the ouput display is still "Weeknd".I replaced all case 0 to case 7 with case Sun to case Sat.Am I clear ?

Comment: Yes, except what you say can't happen, and you've still not explained what *throwing me error* means. If it works for `Sun` and `Sat`, it works for the other days also. If it doesn't, then either that's not your real code in the question or you've managed to break it when you made the changes I suggested.

Comment: @xavier clarify your purpose please, what do you want specifically

Comment: I am sorry.There is no "throwing me error".My bad,Its first time i am using stack.When I enter Mon,-Fri in console.Output is "weeknd" .It  shouldnt be right ?

Comment: attched is screenshot http://prntscr.com/mkumcv

Comment: Seems fine to me. *shrug* https://ideone.com/zTmgPj If you're expecting to be able to enter the enum value as text you have more work to do to parse that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to do something that cannot be done.

Comment: Based on your restrictions I'd guess this is homework. This may fit the restrictions, but it does have a bug in it that I'll leave you to find. Good luck! https://ideone.com/cRybDi

Answer (score 0):

Please note that:

> Each **switch** action is associated with the value of an integral constant
>   expression (i.e., any combination of character and integer constants
>   that evaluates to a constant integer value).

From the previous statement we see that it OK to use the `enum` values inside the `switch cases` because the `enum` values are treated as numbers.

So in your case, it is not possible to make the user enter a `string` input and then  you check that input in a `switch case`. Before using the input with `switch case`, you should convert the user input (whatever it was) to an **integral constant expression** so that you can use inside the `switch case`.
You may also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510859/c11-and-constant-expression-evaluation-in-switch-case-labels), I think it is helpful for you.

Comment: The code says `int day; cin >> day;`. That reads the input into an `int`, so there is no issue of trying to use a `string`. Further, the expression in `switch(expr)` does not have to be a constant expression. Indeed, if it was, there would be no point in using a `switch` statement. You're right that the `case` labels require an integral constant expression, but that's not an issue here, because they all are.

Answer (score 0):

Switches are used for checking against integral constants so you *can* actually switch on the enumerated values you have, such as with:

```
switch (day) {
    case Mon: case Tue: case Wed: case Thu: case Fri:
        cout << "Weekday"; break;
    case Sun: case Sat:
        cout << "Weekend"; break;
    default:
        cout << "??"; break;
}
cout << '\n';
```

---

However, you can't *enter* the enumerated values in the way you expect, entering the word `Tue` and having that magically converted to the value `2`. If you have the following code:

```
int x = 42;
std::cin >> x;
```

and you enter a non-numeric like `Tue`, `x` will *not* be any useful value that you can use. That's almost certainly the reason why, as you mention in a comment, it tells you it's the weekend no matter which *textual* day you enter. There's a good chance they *all* set `x` to zero (Sunday) because they cannot be immediately interpreted as an integer.

---

What you *can* do to allow textual input is to provide a function which does that conversion work for you, something like the one shown in this complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int getDayOfWeek(std::string textDay) {
    // Only use up to three characters, and lower-case.

    std::string day = textDay.substr(0,3);
    std::transform(day.begin(), day.end(), day.begin(), ::tolower);

    // Search through collection until found then return index.

    int dayOfWeek = 0;
    for (std::string chk: {"sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"}) {
        if (day == chk) return dayOfWeek;
        ++dayOfWeek;
    }

    // Not found, return sentinel value.

    return -1;
}

// Test harness to allow you to enter arbitrary lines and
// convert them to day indexes. Hit ENTER on its own to stop.

int main() {
    std::string day;
    std::cout << "Enter day: "; std::getline(std::cin, day);
    while (!day.empty()) {
        std::cout << day << " --> " << getDayOfWeek(day) << '\n';
        std::cout << "Enter day: "; std::getline(std::cin, day);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The "meat" of this is the `getDayOfWeek()` function which, given a string, can tell you what day of the week that string represents (if any). Once you *have* it as an integer, it's a simple matter to use a `switch` statement on it, such as:

```
std::string getDayClass(std::string day) {
    switch getDayOfWeek(day) {
        case 0: case 6:
            return "weekend";
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
            return "weekday";
    }
    return "unknown";
}
```

Keep in mind I've used *specific* rules for decoding the textual day into an integer, checking only the first three characters, and in lowercase,

so `WEDDED BLISS` as input will see it thinking it's a Wednesday. Obviously you can make the rules more (or less) restrictive as the situation requires.

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this:

```
int main()
{
    string day;
    cout << " Enter a day ";
    cin >> day;
    if (day == "Sun")
    {
        cout << "Weekend" << endl;
    }
    else if (day == "Mon")
    {
        cout << "Start of work week " << endl;
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its still throwing me weeknd for Mon-Fri even though i replaced the refered code

Comment: I think I understand what you want now - updated the answer.

Comment: I know code for if else but I only need to use switch using enum  for the current code.

Comment: You can't use `switch` for string input.  It's for integral values only.

Comment: yeah true i cannot only char ,int ,enum and boolean.can you fix for me with my current code

Comment: Like I said - it's not possible.